# Using vue 3 vue-i18n build-in modifiers in code/template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-i18n

Vue 3s' i18n [plugin](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/) has [build-in modifiers](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/essentials/syntax.html#built-in-modifiers) for (linked) messages.

```
 message: {
      edit: 'edit',
      editDesc: '@. capitalize:edit description'
    }
```

which works fine, but the problem is I couldn't find a way to use those modifiers from within a template.

For example if I want an edit button with an capitalized 'e': `<button>Edit</button>`

```
<button>
  {{ $t("edit") }}
</button>
```

i tried several things:

```
<button>
  {{ $t("edit.capitalize") }}
</button>

<button>
  {{ $t("capitalize.edit") }}
</button>

<button>
  {{ $t(":capitalize.edit") }}
</button>
```

but none of these worked.

Is it even possible to use those modifiers in a template/from code, or to I have to use plain `js` for it.

If it is possible, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modifiers can only used in i18n config messages, I suggest to define the message with capitalized format and lower it when it used in the middle/end of sentence :

```js
 message: {
      edit: 'Edit',
      editDesc: '@:message.edit description',
      editApprove: 'Please approve the @.lower:message.edit'
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it easiest to modify this in the template using plain JavaScript String methods.  It has been more useful in my experience to store the message strings capitalized, then use the toLowerCase method.

```js
<button>
  {{ $t("edit").toLocaleLowerCase() }}
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. As a workaround I use temporary linked message:

```
message: {
  tmp: 'Actual text',
  content: "@.lower:tmp"
}
```

And then in the template:

```
<p>{{ $t('message.content') }}</p>
```

It's ugly tho...